# When running a python script from command line, PythonWin also runs. How can I avoid this?

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to run a script from the command line (command prompt). I type:

```
python.exe full_script_path.py parameters
```

And for some reason, PythonWin opens up. I have to close it for execution to finish. Unfortunately, this keeps me from being able to do multiple executions in a batch file.

What can I do to avoid PythonWin from opening?

Comment: Did you try pythonw.exe instead of python.exe?

Comment: Yes, it still opened PythonWin. I also tried renaming to .pyw (which uses pythonw.exe) and got the same result.

Comment: It turns out I had this Python-Win32 module installed. I removed that, then reset my file associations to use pythonw.exe, and it worked again. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should launch `pythonw.exe` instead of plain `python.exe`, but I am not on a windows box right now, so I cannot test it.

Comment: Hi, sorry, that still opened PythonWin.

Comment: It turns out I had this Python-Win32 module installed. I removed that, then reset my file associations to use pythonw.exe, and it worked again. Thanks for your reply!